# "-Не-" кратким прилагательным

Tags: орфография

"Правотворчество и законотворчество не тождественны друг другу" — слово с *не-* написано верно?

Answer (score 1):

Слово *тождественны* - краткая форма относительного прилагательного. *Не* с краткими прилагательными пишется в основном так же, как с полными.
У Розенталя говорится, что как правило, **не** пишется раздельно с относительными прилагательными, придавая отрицание выражаемому ими признаку. При этом учитывается синтаксическая функция прилагательного: правило обычно распространяется на прилагательные в роли сказуемого, так как предполагаемое противопоставление придает высказыванию характер общеотрицательного суждения, выражаемого частицей **не**.
Нужно писать раздельно: *правотворчество и законотворчество не тождественны друг другу*.